# Scraping an image with Google Sheet functions

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, image-extraction

I'm trying to extract some images from a website with Google Sheets in a cell. I find some solutions but it's not working everytime.

What I want to do?
I need to be able to paste a URL and get image's itself and also images embedded URL.

Here is the page that I want to extract - but not only this one. I want to use one column with URL's and other two columns as Image and Image's direct URL.

https://www.freepik.com/free-photo/full-length-cheerful-woman-sweater-posing-with-arm-hip-hile-pointing-looking-away-white-wall_6730124.htm#query=full%20length%20portrait%20of%20a%20pointing%20finger&position=2&from_view=search&track=sph

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=LAMBDA(x, {IMAGE(x), x})(QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1, "//img/@src"), 
 "where Col1 contains 'img.'", ))
```

[image]